# Adding an array formula to an Excel spreadsheet using PHP

Tags: php, export-to-excel, pear

I'm generating an excel spreadsheet using the PEAR extension, Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer. I need to add an [array formula](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArrayFormulas.aspx) to one of the cells, but all the info I've read about them only discusses them as if you're in the Excel program itself: it says you have to type in the formula as normal and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to switch it to an array formula.

Is there a way I can do this programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

There is a property called `FormulaArray` that allows array formulas to be entered programmatically.  Hopefully this is exposed to you from your PHP extension.

Usage:

```
Sheet1.Range("C1:C3").FormulaArray = "=(A1:A3)*(B1:B3)"
```

Comment: How can I execute Sheet1.Range("C1:C3").FormulaArray = "=(A1:A3)*(B1:B3)" from php via PHPExcel class? Thank you!